# 127.0.0.1 refused to connect on all ports (windows 11)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-11, localhost

I first thought this problem was related to my new install of the Plex media server (installed on Windows 11 laptop), but the problem seems bigger than that. The issue is that neither localhost nor 127.0.0.1 are reachable regardless of port specified, not just port 32400 used by Plex. Chrome states "This site can’t be reached. 127.0.0.1 refused to connect".

The really weird part is that the server was up and the clients successfully connected to it when I first set everything up a few nights ago, and then stopped working the following morning despite me having made no changes. Tried rebooting my PC and my router and as expected, this made no difference.

I looked at another Stack Overflow Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543443/cant-access-127-0-0-1 but none of the offered solutions solved my problem. Unlike the OP in that post, my issue is that neither localhost nor 127.0.0.1 are connecting.

Really stumped and appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Are you connecting from within the same computer in which is installed Plex?

Comment: Yes. I have since resolved the issue by reinstalling Plex. But the question remains, why was this become a problem in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem must have been a bad installation of Plex, which was just
not listening on the port.

The error "127.0.0.1 refused to connect" is misleading, and just means
that no app was listening on the port, so the connection didn't work.

I don't know what went wrong with the first installation, perhaps some
wrong installation option, but this was fixed with the next installation
where the correct options were selected.
If Plex needs to open these ports in the Windows firewall during
the installation, perhaps this was not done in the first one and it
was the firewall that actually blocked access.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem the only thing I changed for it not to work was I set up Plex to start up before login which I created with NSSM.
After logging in I was unable to connect to the server.
I disable the Plex start up in services and then selected start up at login on the Plex taskbar icon, rebooted and everything worked fine